# Create random username for Devise user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I'm using Devise in a rails 4 app.

Users have a username that is not required on sign up, but I want to assign one randomly to them.

I've made the below controller and made sure that :username is in the strong parameters.

The username is not being saved. Can you help me understand why?

```
class UsersController < DeviseController
  before_create :set_username

  private
    def set_username
      o = [1..9].map { |i| i.to_a }.flatten
      self.username = "user" + (0...10).map { o[rand(o.length)] }.join
    end
end
```

Comment: Just so you understand the difference, controllers do not have a lifecycle in rails because they just handle a request.  Objects that inherit from ActiveRecord::Base (your models, like User, Company, Car, etc) are created, saved, destroyed, etc.  Those are things you can call before_create and such on.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying that. That's a really helpful way to remember it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using self inside a controller. Inside a controller, self refers to the controller itself. So when you're saying self.username, it refers to variable username on the controller, and not on the model.

Also you should use [SecureRandom](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveSupport/SecureRandom) for generating truly unique ids.

EDIT: Moving the code to the user model.

EDIT 2: Using after_create

Try changing your code to,

```
class User
  #use after create for setting the username
  after_create :set_username

  private
    def set_username
       self.username = "user-#{ SecureRandom.hex(10)}"
    end
end
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Great, thanks for pointing those things out! Unfortunately, it's still not saving. Could there be a problem with my route? I have post 'signup' => 'devise/registrations#create'

Comment: My bad. The code never hits here. I just noticced that You're using before_create callback on the controller. This is an ActiveRecord call back and can be used only within model. Please move the code to the User.rb model. I've updated my code to reflect this change

Comment: Thanks. I understand now why it needs to be in the model. It's still not saving the username though. Any idea why?

Comment: Ok, just changed it back to before_create and that worked! Thanks again for the help!